# Jenkins running builds and tests all day long

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I would like Jenkins to be in a permanent loop of running the jobs which have been configured.

How can i configure Jenkins to keep running builds and tests all day long and just keeping a log of the results?

Comment: IMO it's better to add a hook into your version control check-in (or commit) process.

Comment: Hi Elliott, I understand that hooking into the version control system is the normal way to do things but I am looking to have the server run continuous builds and tests for a whole week maybe a month hopefully someone knows how to do this with Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the job to run periodically every 10 minutes by going to the job configuration. There enable the checkbox - "Build periodically" and set the time format - 
Eg: this builds it every 15 minutes -
H/15 * * * *

Comment: what will happen if the job hasnt finished and the timer to run again expires? 
will it build it at the next available time or just start another instance?

Comment: It will build at the next available time - the jenkins slave can only run one job at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vanval, as he pointed me in the right direction by searching for "building periodically" you can find more answers here:
https://superuser.com/questions/751103/need-to-schedule-a-job-every-hour-in-jenkins

especially here:
https://superuser.com/a/751110

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer if it satisfies your requirement.